# Stack Overflow questions without a concrete answer

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

I've asked a [question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16190679/3d-viewer-for-net) and the question was closed. I would like to understand why.

I've asked for general guidance on a specific technical matter, and I was looking for opinions and shared experience. I understand these kind of questions are no longer welcomed on Stack Overflow, and I would like to understand why. Stack Overflow is filled with old questions of this sort, and it used to be a good place to share, and ask for guidance and advice, when did the community decide these kind of discussions don't belong there?

Also, where have you gone with these questions?

Comment: Because most opinions stink. And it helps us all. In the words of Ayn Rand (from Atlas Shrugged): _'You should spare yourself the embarrassing discovery of their exact value to your listener.'_ SO makes the temptation itself something of a taboo, but does give an outlet for the frustrated via comments.

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment I suggest you take a look at the question... the alternative to asking for opinions on this, would be to write POC's for something like 10 libraries

Comment: You don't have to use the alternative to asking for opinions though even if you can't ask for opinions here. Just ask somewhere else. :)

Comment: Is there a stackExchange site for "Software related advice"?

Comment: @Hellfrost: Not that i'm aware of, I meant somewhere else on the internet.

Comment: StackOverflow simply is not the place for such discussions. There is nothing inherently bad about them but people come to SO/SE to find _answers_ to specific _problems_ they're facing. It's off topic. SO is not a discussion forum.

Answer (score 1):

These questions have always been against the "rules" which say what questions belong on this site. However, earlier on the site had a smaller community and consisted mainly of well experienced developers who could generally answer such questions well.

Nowadays though the site has over a million registered users. Many of these users are new to programming and computers in general, and English is often not their first language. Due to this, the community has had to become more strict with questions like this to prevent a flood of questions asking for opinions and experiences over questions that can be answered with facts.

You could try finding some mailing lists that could help you with questions like this one. They are far more suited to opinionated discussions than Stack Overflow.

Comment: but have a far smaller and usually less diverse community

Comment: @Hellfrost Yes, but that would also be a community more focused on the topic of the list, and having a smaller community means anything posted is likely to get more attention. It evens out, IMHO